# determine the probability of each value multiple rolls of dice. stop once same number shown N times

Tags: probability

Trying help my daughter with a problem.

The problem:
Two dice. Each numbered 1-6. Both dice are rolled at the same time to get one of 11 values in the range 2-12.
The 11 values have a different probability of occurring:
Number 2 has 1/36 probability of being rolled each time (1 + 1).
Number 3 has 2/36 probability of being rolled each time (1 + 2 and 2 + 1).
and so on.

Keep rolling the dice until one of the values has been rolled N times. The first value to be rolled N times is the winner.
For each of the 11 values work out the probability of that value being the winner.

Independent event probability means the multiplication of probabilities.

For N = 2, the probability of getting 3 twice in two rolls is (2/36 * 2/36) = 4/1296 = 1/324.
Which means the probability of *not* getting 3 twice in two rolls is (2/36 * 34/36 + 34/36 * 34/36 + 34/36 * 2/36) = (68/1296 + 1156/1296 + 68/1296) = 1292/1296 = 323/324

But this problem allows me to keep rolling the dice until I get the same value come up N times.
Still assuming N = 2, that would the maximum would be rolling all the numbers once, then rolling the  1*11 + 1 = 12. I would need to roll the dice between two and 12 times to guarantee to get two matching values. 
I assume I need to add up the various probabilities for rolling 2 to 12 times.

I start having trouble because I don't have/know a formula which calculates the probabilities of the different permutations for the different number of rolls.

e.g The value 3 would win if you rolled 12 times getting 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,11,10,3 probability of ((2/36)^2 * (34/36)^12), but how many permutations?

The value 3 also wins in these cases rolling only four times.
1,2,3,3 probability of ((2/36)^2 * (34/36)^2) is the same as 3,1,2,3 and so on

But value 3 doesn't win in this case 3,1,1,3, so I can't just apply ((2/36)^2 * (34/36)^2) * NumberOfPermutations.

Ultimately want to solve for N=8

Comment: This seems like an application of the multinomial distribution see [multinomial distribution][1] and [multinomial theorem][2] for more info. I can't see a simple closed form for this since it involves the sum of multinomial coefficients where only the term representing our desired sum has an exponent greater than or equal to $N$ and all others are less than $N$.

[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution
[2]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: Clearly for $N=1$ the chance for $7$ to win is six times the chance for $2$ to win and so on.  I strongly suspect that for $N=2$ the chance for each number is proportional to the square of its probability on one roll, so $7$ would win $36$ times as often as $2$, but I don't see a proof.

Comment: @RossMillikan: That seemed an appealing thought, but if you have a (usually unfair) coin that flips H with probability $p$ and T with probability $q=1-p$, you get two H first with probability $p^2(p+3q)$, and two T first with probability $q^2(q+3p)$, and those are not in the ratio $p^2$ to $q^2$.  (For instance, with $p = 2/3$, the probabilities are $20/27$ and $7/27$.)  This seems a rather thorny problem for $N = 8$.

Comment: If my experiment is correct, with $N=2$, $7$ comes up about $24$ times as often as $2$ (perhaps a little less than $24$...).

Comment: @MatthewConroy: Confirmed by direct numerical analysis of the $N = 2$ case.  The two probabilities are $2464012795318281/36^{11} \doteq 0.0187$, and $58197398895009288/36^{11} \doteq 0.442$, with a ratio of about $23.6$.  (I'd have to write my code better to extend it to $N = 8$.)

Comment: Unfortunately, the winning numbers are not conditionally independent; that is, you cannot find the ratio of $7$ winning to $2$ winning by pretending those are the only two possibilities, and then normalizing the probabilities.  Knowing that (for instance) $4$ didn't win changes the ratio of $7$ winning to $2$ winning.

Comment: @BrianTung I'd love to see the code you used for that calculation if you are able to post it anywhere.  Cheers!

Comment: @MatthewConroy: You'll go blind looking at this code; it's awful (and it's in C).  If I get it into a state where it's reasonable to extend to $N = 8$, I may post it.

Comment: ATTN: due to the complexity of the problem and that it was for a Year 8 assessment, I asked my daughter's teacher for clarification.  The teacher was only wanting the student to calculate the probability of rolling the same number eight times in a row. But the question's wording didn't state any limits on the number of rolls. Thanks for all the comments and I apologise on behalf on the Y8 teacher. Now how do I close this question?

Comment: You should be able to delete the question yourself.